# Symfony thinks a file is not a file

Tags: symfony

I am getting the following error in Symfony:

Resource "/var/www/symfony/config/api_platform/Stats/Stats.xml" is not a file.

It DOES exist and it IS a file. Any ideas?

Comment: That's not symfony but PHP as Symfony uses `is_file` under the hood.

Possible issue for this are:

- Folder permissions (along the path, starting from root)
- File dimensions (more than 2GB can produce unexpected results)
- File does really not exists

Comment: It was indeed permission issues, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

So this was a problem with Docker, somehow some files and directories ended up chmod'ed wrong; chmodding them to 777 resolved the issue

Comment: Try 644 / 755 instead, not sure you want to keep it as 777